# INSERT multiple rows INTO one table, with each record's columns having different reference values

Tags: mysql, sql, join, insert

I have three tables:

> Movie [mID, title, year, director]
>   Rating [rID (foreign key), mID (foreign key), stars, ratingDate]
>   Reviewer [rID, name]

I have to insert, into table Rating, a review by "James" (present in table Reviewer) giving 5 stars to every movie in the database, leaving the ratingDate as "NULL"

So far I've been able to JOIN James's rID with every mID in table Movie.

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT rID FROM reviewer WHERE name = "James") AS a LEFT JOIN (SELECT mID FROM movie) AS b ON 1=1;
```

What I don't know is how to add the 5 stars and NULL ratingDate to each one of those entries, and finally append all those to my Rating table.

My question is if it can all be done in one query (with multiple subqueries I imagine), or if I'm taking the wrong approach. It seems like a relatively simple problem but I can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: Is using a server side programming language acceptable to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO Rating(rID, mID, stars, ratingDate)
  SELECT r.rID, m.mID, 5, NULL
  FROM Movie m CROSS JOIN
       (SELECT r.Rid
        FROM Reviewer r
        WHERE r.name = 'James'
       ) r
```

Note the following:

- The columns are explicitly listed in the `insert` statement.
- The tables in the `select` query are given aliases, which are abbreviations for the table names.
- The `CROSS JOIN` is used, because there really is not a join condition between `Movie` and `Reviewer`.
- The string literal (`'James'`) is enclosed in single quotes rather than double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
INSERT INTO Rating
  SELECT
    Reviewer.rID,
    Movie.mID,
    5,
    NULL
  FROM
    Movie
    INNER JOIN Reviewer ON Reviewer.name="James"
```

Explanation:

- The combination of INNER JOIN and the strange ON clause cares for the edge case, where James does not exist as a reviewer
- The field list selects the needed fields

Answer (score 0):

--Inserting data for your requirements:
INSERT INTO Rating ( rid, mid, stars, ratingDate)
SELECT r.rID,
       m.mID,
       5,
       NULL
FROM Movie m
JOIN Reviewer r ON (r.name="James");

In addition, I'd suggest to put following index if you execute similar "SELECT" statement regularly:
create index idx_reviewer_name on Reviewer(name);

I would like to remind you to put current date as the default value of ratingDate field. It helps you to ensure current date by database itself if you need to insert rating date automatically.

Thanks.